# How to change indent size for typescript layer in Spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs

I have a `tsfmt.json` file with

```
{
  "indentSize": 2,
  "tabSize": 2
}
```

which *does* get picked up appropriately by tide when running `M-x tide-format`.

But when I start a new line by pressing RET or 'o', it gets indented 4 spaces. How do I change this?

---

Using Spacemacs v.0.200.10 on GNU Emacs 27.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0, NS appkit-1504.83 Version 10.12.6 (Build 16G29)) of 2017-09-17

---

Repro:
[image: asciicast]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is a variable called `typescript-indent-level` that, by default is set to 4. For Spacemacs specifically, you can change the value of this variable by directly setting it in your `dotspacemacs/user-config` function like so:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  (setq-default typescript-indent-level 2))
```

Comment: for plain emacs just  (setq-default typescript-indent-level 2) inside .emacs working

Comment: This answer may now be out of date, on spacemacs version `0.999.0` I have no such variable when inside a `tsx` file, and, in setting it as a `typescript` variable, it had no effect on my `tsx` files

Comment: @CalebJay does [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/72010/14825) help? Or maybe [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/74682/14825)?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem with `.tsx` files.  Turns out you also have to set the variable `web-mode-code-indent-offset` to your preferred indent level as well.

If you go `M-x` `customize` then search for the variable you can set it there and it will automatically update your config files.

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize this configuration with the layer.

In your `~/.spacemacs` file, you can set your layers like this..

```lisp
   dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
   '(systemd
     (typescript :variables
                 typescript-indent-level 2
                 )
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides the accepted answer there was a comment about *.tsx files.
The indention of *.tsx files is controlled by typescript-tsx mode, which is inheriting the settings from web-mode, which is covered by the html layer.

I have the following in my dotspacemac/layers:

```
   (html :variables
         web-mode-markup-indent-offset 2
         web-mode-code-indent-offset 2
         web-mode-css-indent-offset 2
         web-mode-sql-indent-offset 2
   )
   (typescript :variables
         typescript-indent-level 2
   )
```

This will set the indention level to 2 in both modes.